# Top Hour Countdown Timer Android

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

How do i make a countdown timer that always counts down to the nearest Top hour.
For example if the time is 6:30pm it would automatically start counting down the mumber of minutes and seconds to  7:00pm

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the total milliseconds between the two times and then the rest is just display work.  You could use a CountDownTimer to update the display.

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar nextHour = Calendar.getInstance();
nextHour.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
nextHour.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
nextHour.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

long difference = nextHour.getTimeInMillis() - now.getTimeInMillis();

new CountDownTimer(difference, 1000) {

public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        mTextField.setText("done!");
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: Why not getting Calendar.Minute as an integer, then do 60 - minutes every second for display?

Comment: @Adam W am a bit of a newbie can you show how to add the async task to update every second?

Comment: @MekunuStudio updated with some more code.  Just make a layout file with a text field and you can update it as shown.  Feel free to mark correct if this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Get the current time, in the current time, get the minutes. Do 60 - the current number of minutes?

Comment: Thanks, can you show how to do this in code?

Comment: @Adam W it works , but can you convert it to minutes and seconds. It currently displays in milisenconds only